# Finding a number in a website and displaying it

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to take the "total member" number (on the right bar of the website) and display that number inside a label in C# windows form application. Here is the website: https://www.dojrp.com/
Thanks

Comment: it says that the 3 word "[HtmlDocument]" is not valid in the given context.

Comment: Of course, that is meant to be your `webBrowser1.Document`. Also, the number is inside a `SPAN`, not a `DIV` (my bad), so the actual code would be: `HtmlElement element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("SPAN").OfType<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(elm => elm.GetAttribute("className").Equals("ipsDataItem_stats_number"));`. The number is then in `string Number = element.InnerHtml;`. Remember to set `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`, that's a dynamic page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to solve your problem:

Step 1. Get the html code of this website page using System.Net.WebClient class.

Step 2. Locate the "total member" number in the html code and get it using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class.

Step 3. Assign that number to your label on your windows form.

Comment: Trolling newcomers with Regex… like it!!! (whoever reads the answer - please  make your life easier and use HTML parsers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c is much better guidance and following is good read about [html and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/)).